# Stream API (anyMatch(), allMatch(), noneMatch())

Tags: java, потоки-данных, java-stream

> Unlike the anyMatch( ) method that returns false when the stream is empty, the allMatch( ) and noneMatch( ) methods return true if the stream is empty!

Вопрос: Почему в одном случае при пустом стриме возвращается false  а в остальных случаях true?

Просьба: Помочь понять логику, почему все именно так а не иначе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`anyMatch()` не находит в пустом множестве "любой" элемент, удовлетворяющий заданному условию, отчего и возвращает `false`. Тут вроде всё понятно.

`noneMatch()` возвращает истину, так как ни один элемент в пустом множестве не может соответствовать условию. Тут тоже всё ясно.

А вот насчёт `allMatch()` всё не так очевидно).
Тут надо знать о таком утверждении в логике, как "[бессодержательная истина](https://ru.qwertyu.wiki/wiki/Vacuous_truth)", которая утверждает, что все элементы пустого множества соответствуют условию. Ведь вы не можете указать тот элемент, который не соответствует.

Comment: Это редкий случай и я очень рад, что ответ настолько хорош, что даже не пришлось задавать дополнительные вопросы. Спасибо за качественный ответ!